# Merging triangles into a bigger one

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, stroke

I'm trying to make a bigger triangle by merging 2 smaller ones, but I get these strange overlapping corners on the top. What can I do differently to get perfect corners?

Attaching an image to illustrate this issue.

[image: Triangle example]

Comment: What you are seeing are called *miters*. You might want to reduce your miter limit, or change your shapes' corners to rounded ones.

Answer (score 4):

This is a result of your stroke alignment set to center and miter joins.

In the Stroke options panel, there is a "Limit" value (short for [miter limit](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/stroke-object.html#change_the_caps_or_joins_of_a_line)). Setting this to 0 will remove the "strange object parts".

[image: Illustrator Stroke Panel] [image: two triangles]

To add the desired sharp corners back in, add a third border triangle:

[image: three triangles]